# Checkbox in redux form is hidden using Field Type

Tags: redux-form

I have been trying to implement a form using redux form but the checkbox somehow is not appearing or it is hidden from the browser.

does anyone have any ideas why it is not appearing or it's not visible using redux form.

Comment: <Field type="checkbox" name="status" component={renderField} label="status" />

Comment: Hard to say, please share more code.

Comment: yeah just fixed the issues. In redux form when we use checkbox or radio button it becomes hidden from the browser because by default the css opacity property remains 0. we need to change ration of opacity to make the checkbox or radio button visible to the browsers...